# (C#) sending hex over serial

Tags: c#, communication, hardware, type-conversion

So I'm trying to send a (string?) of hex that looks like this "7E 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF"  over a serial port. My code looks like this:

`serialport.write("7E 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF");`

The controller that is receiving it is not acknowledging this data, I'm assuming that the character encoding of the serial port which defaults to ASCII is an issue. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I can get my controller that is receiving it to respond to the data when I send it from a serial terminal program (comviewer); I send it out as a hex string, and the data is sent all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that you are using the [SerialPort Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(v=vs.110).aspx), right?

Then, I think you want to parse your string, convert the hex values to bytes and then write the bytes directly.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
string str = "7E 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF";
byte[] bytes = str.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
serialport.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Ah, SerialPort Class must have been what was mean by "serial port". My head was hurting trying to figure how hardware has a character encoding.

Comment: Awesome I'll try this tomorrow and post back my results!

Answer (score 1):

The value 0xFF is used to signify UART Rx buffer empty, and therefore the need to convert to representative ASCII bytes over conventional serial to avoid this value.